# uWSGI resets worker on lifetime reached causes downtime

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I have uWSGI running Django. I configured my uWSGI workers to have max-worker-lifetime=3600.

What I see is that every 3600 seconds, both uWSGI workers terminate together, and this causes downtime of about 10-15 seconds, with all to the server failing with 502 from the remote server.

These are the logs:

```
Everything normal

00:00:00 worker 1 lifetime reached, it was running for 3601 second(s)
00:00:00 worker 2 lifetime reached, it was running for 3601 second(s)

00:00:01 HTTP 502 (on the remote server)
00:00:01 HTTP 502 (on the remote server)
...
00:00:11 HTTP 502 (on the remote server)
00:00:11 HTTP 502 (on the remote server)

00:00:11 Respawned uWSGI worker 1 (new pid: 66)
00:00:11 Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 67)

Everything goes back to normal
```

I'm not sure why it has this behavior.

This is the configuration used (only relevant parts):

```
    UWSGI_MASTER=true \
    UWSGI_WORKERS=2 \
    UWSGI_THREADS=8 \
    UWSGI_LISTEN=250 \
    UWSGI_LAZY_APPS=true \
    UWSGI_WSGI_ENV_BEHAVIOR=holy \
    UWSGI_MAX_WORKER_LIFETIME=3600 \
    UWSGI_RELOAD_ON_RSS=1024 \
    UWSGI_SINGLE_INTERPRETER=true \
    UWSGI_VACUUM=true
```

Comment: Have you tried using the cheaper subsystem (https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Cheaper.html) for the dynamic worker management? It has an option for the minimum number of workers to keep at all times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a parameter that has been recently added through a community contribution `max-worker-lifetime-delta`

https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/2020

https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/pull/2021

This will make sure your workers don't restart so close. Also since your workers have a heavy loading time, have enough workers so that worker restart doesn't have a large impact.

Also you are using a worker timeout which looks quite low, you should experiment with that too and increase it to a value which you find is better

Comment: But that's a little bit "random" isn't it? I can't know when will each worker reach its max-requests. And potentially it can happen exactly at the same time. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you see documentation it mentions `"add (worker_id * delta) seconds to the max_worker_lifetime value of each worker",` for this new parameters, so if you have 4 workers and worker lifetime as 30 and delta as 10, then first worker will restart at 30 sec, 2nd at 40sec, 3rd at 50sec, so this will make sure you don't get restarts together

Comment: I mean max-requests. Where each worker can have different values

Comment: Don't use that I would suggest